# Why would the Default Gateway constantly require resetting?

Tags: windows-7, internet-connection

I've had a (mostly) steady internet connection for the past two months. For the last hour, however, my connectivity has been dropping every 10 minutes or so, and must be reset.

So far, I've always been able to fix the issue by running Windows network diagnostics (On Windows 7 64 bit), but the lack of constant internet is making it a pain to try and stream video, download games through steam, etc.

Windows always reports a fix by "Resetting the Local Area Connector", telling me: `Default Gateway Not Available`.

What's going on? Is the trouble on my end, or with my ISP? (Timewarner Cable)

**Things I've Tried:**

- Reinstalling the motherboard's LAN drivers
- Manually setting a default gateway (gets cleared, reverts to default settings)
- Unplugged (Hard Reset) the router
- Unplugged / replugged ethernet cable.

Comment: Did you restart the router/modem? Do a hard reset of the device?

Comment: @moab Yes, I did. No router, just straight from the modem.

Comment: Is it possible that your DHCP lease is expiring and/or being invalidated?  Check you IP address network information by doing an 'ipconfig'

Comment: @Art What should I be looking for?

Comment: Take a look at your IP Address and default gateway when the internet connection is not working, and then check again after 'fixing' it.

Comment: Usually your router fills the role of the default gateway, so if Windows says the default gateway isn't available, that suggests a problem between your computer and router. You might want to search online to see if others with the same network adapter (or firewall or router) as you have gotten the "default gateway not available" error message and if they found a solution. What is the brand and model of your modem, router, and network adapter? Does your computer connect wirelessly or wired? What firewall software, if any, is used? Are other computers in your home maintaining a good connection?

Comment: @Art Will update when it fails again. It seems to have stabilized for the time being.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this has not repeated itself, and lasted almost exactly two hours, I'm going to conclude that this was a problem on the ISP's end.

Thanks a bunch for the heads up, Timewarner! :/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like some probelem with the ISP. Reset your ISP modem and then run "ipconfig /renew " on your PC.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! How is this shorter answer better than the older longer one?